# 404 when programmatically adding products to magento

Tags: php, magento, csv

I have been working on an integration from CSV files to magento, the integration was started by another person and abandonded so i am working with their code to try and finish it. There are around 7000 products to import and custom pricing for groups as well.

Without adding code here (which i can do if need be) is there anyone with an idea about why when i run the importer it eventually ends up showing the magento 404 page?

If i only import categories, customer groups and customers assigned to groups it runs fine. However if i run proudct importing it is producing the same result.

If i comment out any code that adds the products, the looping over the CSV works correctly and continues to redirect and send me emails with the counter reporting. It only appears to happen when importing.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you may be hitting some file size or import size limit.  How big in KB is the file that you are importing?  You might want to try importing only one product to test.

Comment: Hey, the file is 3268KB the script opens the file and imports 1 - X rows depending how the config is setup. Then it redirects to itself and the incrementer moves accordingly. If i just run the iteration over the file and dont engage any magento product saving it runs all the way to the end of the 7000 products.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you run the script with a browser and I do not think your server is able to treat correctly a bunch of products like that on the php limited time.

If so, you should set up a cron job that does the deal. If you need to upload the file by yourself. You can create a script that set a cron in the next ten minutes for example. I dealt with larger catalog but only with this method, even on a small server. Additionnaly, I would advise you to end up with a fixed time cron job to avoid server overload during the peak hours.